# How do I split and group json data according to its value?

Tags: javascript, json

I don't know how to describe my question properly so I will demonstrate it instead,

I have this json data, a data extracted from an excel file, wherein payslip information of every employee is listed inside the excel file,

I want to extract that data per employee,

My first step was to convert the excel file into json data,

I used sheetjs to convert the excel file into json,

Here's the excel file,
[image]

Here's the json I got from extracting.

```
"Payslip": [

    [
      "Name: Employee1",
      null,
    ],
    [
      "Earnings",
      "Amount",
      "Deductions",
      "Amount",
      "Take Home"
    ],
    [
      "Regular",
      "2,500.00",
      "Coop Loan",
      "1,500.00"
    ],
    [
      "Overtime",
      "1,500.00",
      "Tax",
      "2,200.00"
    ],
    [
      "Holidays",
      "700.00"
    ],
    [
      "Bonus",
      "1,000.00"
    ],
    [
      null,
      "5,700.00",
      null,
      "3,700.00",
      "2,000.00"
    ],
    [
      "Name/Signature/Role/Date: ",
      null,
      "Officer Name"
    ],

     [
      "Name: Employee2",
      null,
    ],
    [
      "Earnings",
      "Amount",
      "Deductions",
      "Amount",
      "Take Home"
    ],
    [
      "Regular",
      "3,500.00",
      "Coop Loan",
      "1,300.00"
    ],
    [
      "Overtime",
      "1,500.00",
      "Tax",
      "2,200.00"
    ],
    [
      "Holidays",
      "700.00"
    ],
    [
      "Bonus",
      "1,000.00"
    ],
    [
      null,
      "5,700.00",
      null,
      "3,700.00",
      "2,000.00"
    ],
    [
      "Name/Signature/Role/Date: ",
      null,
      "Officer Name"
    ],

     [
      "Name: Employee3",
      null,
    ],
    [
      "Earnings",
      "Amount",
      "Deductions",
      "Amount",
      "Take Home"
    ],
    [
      "Regular",
      "2,500.00",
      "Coop Loan",
      "4,500.00"
    ],
    [
      "Overtime",
      "1,500.00",
      "Tax",
      "2,200.00"
    ],
    [
      "Holidays",
      "700.00"
    ],
    [
      "Bonus",
      "1,000.00"
    ],
    [
      null,
      "5,700.00",
      null,
      "3,700.00",
      "2,000.00"
    ],
    [
      "Name/Signature/Role/Date: ",
      null,
      "Officer Name"
    ]
]
```

Now my problem is how do I group the json data per employee,

the output should be something like this,

```
{
    "title": "Requirements List",
    "employees": 
        [
            {
                "name": "Employee1",
                "earnings": 
                    [
                        {
                            "title": "Holiday"
                            "amount": "1,500.00"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Regular"
                            "amount": "2,500.00"
                        }
                    ],
                "deductions": 
                    [
                        {
                            "title": "Loan",
                            "amount": "500.00"
                        }
                    ],
                "total_earnings": "4,000.00",
                "total_deductions": "500.00",
                "take_home": "3,500.00"
            },
            {
                "name": "Employee2",
                "earnings": 
                    [
                        {
                            "title": "Holiday"
                            "amount": "2,500.00"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Regular"
                            "amount": "3,500.00"
                        }
                    ],
                "deductions": 
                    [
                        {
                            "title": "Loan",
                            "amount": "1500.00"
                        }
                    ],
                "total_earnings": "5,000.00",
                "total_deductions": "1500.00"
                "take_home": "3,500.00"
            }
        ]
}
```

I want to know how do I extract the data per user?

Thank You,

Do you know any other way I could achieve may goal, thank you,

Comment: Loop through the data. Whenever the first element of the array matches `Name:`, extract the name and start a new object in your result. Then add the next elements as properties in that object.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks Barmar, great idea, didn't know there was a simpler way to do it,

Comment: I'm not actually asking for the solution itself but the steps I should do or where do I start, I just dont know how to ask it properly, but your answer helped alot,

Comment: Start by doing it by hand, and think about all the steps you do and the decisions you make. Then translate those into code. That's all that programming is. :)

Comment: @apelidoko can you possibly share a portion of that excel file? I think there might be an easier way than translating it to json straight away.

Comment: sure @NaguibIhab , I was actually thinking of converting it to html tables instead, but it will become messy, so i had to convert it to json instead, i'll upload the excel file